# 78.LeetCode/Subsets problem - Solution accepted using helper function, but Memory Limit Exceeds otherwise

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, subset

I was trying to solve LeetCode medium question Subsets [link (https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/) using Bit manipulation technique.

First I implemented solution as follows :

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        int num=(int)Math.pow(2,nums.length);
        List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
          List<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<>();
          int addNum=nums.length-1;
          while(i>0)
          {
            if((i&1)!=0)
            {
               ls.add(nums[addNum]);
            }
            addNum--;
            i=i>>1;
          }
          ans.add(ls);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

This solution gives Memory Limit Exceeded error upon running.

Upon checking the solutions section, I found a solution implemented by another user exactly same logic as mine, but using a helper function.

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
       List<List<Integer>> ans=new ArrayList<>();
       int num = (int)Math.pow(2,nums.length);
       for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
       {
         List<Integer> ls = helper(i,nums);
         ans.add(ls);
       }
       return ans;
    }
    public List<Integer> helper(int i, int[] nums)
    {
      List<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<>();
      int j=0;
      while(i>0)
      {
         int rem=i&1;
         if(rem==1)
         {
           ls.add(nums[j]);
         }
         j++;
         i=i>>1;
      }
      return ls;
    }
}
```

This solution gets accepted.

Both the codes are basically doing the same. Can someone help me why the first code gives Memory Limit Exceeded.

Comment: *Both the codes are basically doing the same* -- Why don't you tag the actual computer language you are using?  If there is an issue with the way you are using the computer language that causes the difference, then at least someone familiar with the language will point it out.

Comment: *I found a solution implemented by another use exactly same logic as mine, but using a helper function.* -- Then it wasn't exactly the same as yours.  If I did a "diff" on the two sets of code, there are several differences.  I think you are trying to run the program by sight, and not under a debugger that will reveal what the differences are.

Comment: Hello Paul, I'm using Java. I've tagged it now. This is my first question here on stackoverflow, so, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm not saying every line of code matched. The "logic" or the "tactic of solving" the problem was exactly same.

Comment: When you write a program, the computer doesn't care what the "logic" is -- it is going to follow *exactly* what you wrote, whether you made a mistake or not.  Obviously the two codes are not the same with respect to what is actually being executed.  This is why learning how to use a debugger is essential.

Comment: okay, I agree with you that the computer does execute what I ask it to. 
I just need some help from here to know what is wrong in my code, when I know that another piece of code written in a slightly different way yields the expected result.

Comment: `int addNum=nums.length-1;` -- What happens if length is 0?  Your first code does this, while the second doesn't.  This is just one difference that makes a whole lot of difference.  The second thing is that Leetcode gives you the test case that fails -- please [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) both solutions locally with the test case that fails, and maybe you will see why one works while the other doesn't.

Comment: *if length is 0, addNum = 2 power 0 = 1;* -- Is this your guess, or did you read the code I highlighted in the previous comment?  Also please [read this](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).  You have both solutions, you have the test case that fails, what is stopping you from looking at both solutions in the debugger?

Comment: Since you are new here, you are expected to debug the code before asking any questions.  If you expected others to debug the code for you while you wait for answers, that should not be how it works.  At the very least, you should be able to identify *where* your code diverges from the working solution by single-stepping into the debugger.  If you claim it is the "same logic", then debug the working solution first, note what it does at each step, then debug the non-working solution, and determine at which steps the non-working solution goes down a different path than the working solution.

Comment: changed while condition to while(i>0), in first code. It still gives memory limit exceeded. I did debug /dry run/ trace using the test cases. I still coudn't figure out the issue. Which is why I'm here for help.

Comment: Once again -- *debug the working solution first, note what it does at each step, then debug the non-working solution, and determine at which steps the non-working solution goes down a different path than the working solution.*  -- (I just wished that sites like Leetcode had a "debugging" set of questions, where you are given a program that doesn't work and are given points if you can fix it).

Comment: In Java `Solution s = new Solution(); s.subsets( /* the test data that fails */);`.  That is what you should be doing in you main function.  Maybe create two functions, `subsets_working` and `subsets_notworking`, and have the working code in `subsets_working` and the non-working code in `subsets_notworking`.  Then write a `main` that calls both, and debug it in your local Java environment.

Comment: Got it, the problem was, I was destructively modifying 'i' in the while loop, which effected the increments in the outer for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was destructively modifying `i` in the while loop, which effected the increments in the outer for loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).